Conditions for Binomial Distribution
It is known that if $X$ is the sum of $n$ independent and identical Bernoulli random variables, $X$ follows a Binomial distribution.
How about the reverse, can a sum of dependent and/or non-identical Bernoulli random variables still follow a Binomial Distribution?

Is reverse used correctly here?

Yes, certainly.  By this I mean a sum of dependent but not identically distributed Bernoulli variables can have a Binomial distribution.
Let $\mathbf X$ refer to a random vector of zeros and ones of length $n,$ so that there are $2^n$ possible values of $\mathbf X.$  For each such possible vector $\mathbf x$ let $p_{\mathbf x}$ be the probability that $\mathbf X = \mathbf x.$
Observe

The components of $\mathbf X$ (written $X_i,$ $i=1,2,\ldots, n$) are Bernoulli variables with probabilities $p_i.$  These probabilities are the sums of the $p_{\mathbf x}$ over all $\mathbf x$ for which $x_i=1.$

If there is a number $q$ for which the sum of $\mathbf X$ has a Binomial distribution, then (by the definition) the sum of all $p_{\mathbf x}$ where $\mathbf x$ has exactly $k$ components equal to $1$ must equal the Binomial probability: $$\sum_{\mathbf x:\, |\mathbf x|=k}p_{\mathbf x} = \binom{n}{k}q^k(1-q)^{n-k}.$$


The latter constitutes $n+1$ linear constraints on the $2^n$ values of the $p_{\mathbf x}$ and therefore has dimension at least $2^n - (n+1).$  If not all of the $X_i$ have the same distribution, the former translates to the complement of a finite set of linear constraints of the form $p_i\ne p_j$ for all $i\ne j.$  Finally, all $p_i$ must lie within the interval $[0,1].$
Generically, then, given $q$ there is a space of solutions of dimension $2^n-(n+1)$ if there is any solution at all.
Rather than analyze this in more detail, let's move on to the simplest possible example, where $n=2.$  ($n=1$ won't work because $2^1-(1+1)=0$ is not flexible enough.)  Here is a tabulation of the possibilities.
$$\begin{array}[rrrrr]
\text{} & x_1 & x_2 & p_{\mathbf x} & x_1+x_2 & \text{Binomial probability}\\
\hline
& 0 & 0 & p_{00} & 0 & (1-q)^2\\
& 0 & 1 & p_{01} & 1 & (1-q)q\\
& 1 & 0 & p_{10} & 1 & q(1-q) \\
& 1 & 1 & p_{11} & 2 & q^2
\end{array}$$
Collecting lines according to the value of $x_1+x_2$ and equating the probabilities $p$ with the Binomial probability gives three equations,
$$\begin{aligned}
p_{00} &= (1-q)^2\\
p_{01}+p_{10} &= 2q(1-q)\\
p_{11} &= q^2.
\end{aligned}$$
Evidently $q$ determines $p_{00}$ (top line) and $p_{11}$ (bottom line) directly, leaving one more equation
$$p_{01} + p_{10} = 2q(1-q).$$
We seek solutions for which the $p_{*}$ lie in $[0,1].$  They can be parameterized by a number $t$ between $0$ and $2q(1-q).$ The full set of solutions therefore is
$$p = (p_{00}, p_{01}, p_{10}, p_{11}) = ((1-q)^2,\ t,\ 2q(1-q)-t,\ q^2).$$
Moreover, for any $q$ in the interval $(0,1)$ there are infinitely many solutions.  This is our space of $2^2 - (2+1) = 1$ dimensions, parameterized by $t$ and contingent on the choice of $q,$ thereby giving a two-parameter family of possibilities.
The general case (for arbitrarily large $n$) works the same way but has many more solutions.

I will close by remarking that when the $X_i$ are independent, a quick analysis of their characteristic functions shows that their sum can be Binomial$(n,q)$ for some $q$ only when the $X_i$ are identically distributed.  Thus, dependence is essential in the preceding construction.


A sum of independent Bernoulli variables with possibly different parameters is called a poisson-binomial distribution. It has its own tag here, poisson-binomial-distribution, peruse that!

Dropping independence there are very many possibilities, you will need to describe the dependence structure. But there are earlier questions here you should read:



Distribution of the Sum of Dependent Bernoulli Random Variables
What is the distribution of a sum of identically distributed Bernoulli random varibles if each pair has the same correlation?
Decomposing dependent Bernoulli random variables into independent Bernoulli random variables


Although these are all good points and excellent resources, they don't answer the question: to what extent can any of these distribution still be Binomial?  It is possible.  For example, let the probabilities of $(0,0),$ $(0,1),$ and $(1,1)$ be $1/4,$ $1/2,$ and $1/4,$ respectively.  The first coordinate has a Bernoulli$(1/4)$ distribution while the second has a different Bernoulli$(3/4)$ distribution, yet their sum has a Binomial$(2,1/2)$ distribution.

It is possible; here is a concrete example of this happening.
Suppose you roll three fair $6$-sided dice; let $\mathbf X_{ij}$ be the indicator random variable which is $1$ if the $i^{\text{th}}$ die you rolled came up $j$. (Each of these has a $\text{Bernoulli}(p=\frac16)$ distribution.) Then the sum
$$
   \mathbf X_{11} + \mathbf X_{12} + \mathbf X_{13} + 
   \mathbf X_{21} + \mathbf X_{22} + \mathbf X_{23} + 
   \mathbf X_{31} + \mathbf X_{32} + \mathbf X_{33} 
$$
counts the number of dice that come up $1$, $2$, or $3$, which has a $\text{Binomial}(n=3, p=\frac12)$ distribution. In this example, the Bernoulli random variables are identically distributed, but not independent. (If they were independent, the distribution would be $\text{Binomial}(n=9, p=\frac16)$ instead.)
If the dice are loaded and have some other probabilities of rolling each face - for concreteness, let's say they come up $1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6$ with probability $\frac14, \frac16, \frac1{12}, \frac14, \frac16, \frac1{12}$ respectively - then it's possible that the Bernoulli random variables are neither independent nor identically distributed, but we still get the same result. (Here, the $p$ parameter of the resulting Binomial will be the probability of rolling $1$, $2$, or $3$ with a loaded die, which is still $\frac12$ in the case of the concrete loaded die shown above.)

Think of a Galton board
Beads are being dropped down through a maze of pins where at each pin the bead goes either left or right. The result at the end relates to the sum of times that the bead went left or right.
(image from Wikipedia Matemateca (IME/USP)/Rodrigo Tetsuo Argenton)

We can think of such device with the pins having individual and different probabilities (instead all of them having the constant fifty-fifty) such that we still end up with a binomial distribution at the end.
An example is the triangle below

At the the first layer of pins all 100% beads pass.

At the second layer of pins the beads are are split 50%-50%.

In the third layer of pins the beads can end up in a $p^2, 2pq, q^2$ ratio, given the right probabilities for the beads falling left or right.
  First layer:            1
                         / \
                        /   \
  Second layer:       0.5   0.5
                      / \   / \
                     /   \ /   \
  Third layer      p^2   2pq   q^2



If the start is a Bernoulli variable with fifty-fifty probability, we can still have various different end results, for $p^2, 2pq, q^2$ by having specific steps in the second layer. This happens when a fraction $p^2/0.5$ moves to the left on the left bottom Bernoulli variable and if a fraction $q^2/0.5$ moves to the right on the right bottom Bernoulli variable.
Therefore it it is not so difficult to have an example where

a sum of dependent and/or non-identical Bernoulli random variables still follow a Binomial Distribution?


I'm afraid I don't follow this argument, perhaps because the example is incomplete: what do the numbers at its nodes really mean and how do you demonstrate the final result really has a Binomial distribution?
